# How to use wp_set_object_terms depending on page ID?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy, terms, save-post

The function to set custom term works fine.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_custom_term', 30, 2 );

function set_custom_term( $post_id, $post ) {
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'guitar', 'instrument',true); 
}
```

I need to set different terms depending on page ID. The following code didn't worked.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_custom_term', 30, 2 );

function set_custom_term( $post_id, $post ) {
    if (is_page(22)){
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id,'guitar', 'instrument', true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: the page that is being saved, or the page the user is currently on?

Comment: Just check the value of `$post_id`. eg. `if ( $post_id === 22 )`.

Comment: If the page the user is currently on is ID 22, it should `save_post` with term `($post_id,'guitar', 'instrument', true); `.

Comment: The code `if ( $post_id === 22 )` didn't worked.